# Comparing and Replacing C# Result with JSON file

Tags: c#

I have a JSONfile. I will get a Result Data from the previous functionality.
I should compare this result data with the JSON and edit it.
For Example: 
In Currency I will get the result as United States Dollar
Now I have to Compare the JSON
Currencies:

```
{
    "USD": [
        "USD",
        "US Dollars",
        "United States Dollar",
        "US Dollar",
        "$",
        "US$" 
    ]
}
```

And Declare it as USD. How to do this using Dictionary?

Comment: What have you already tried? StackOverflow is not a website for asking people to code something for you, as the question is right now it is too broad. I suggest reading this https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and this https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and then reworking your question

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, this question is a bit unclear. Can you please state what your expected outcome and goal is? For instance, "Declare it as USD", I'm not sure what you mean here. Please help us help you.

Comment: @Lasse I will get output as Currency : United States or sometimes: US Dollar. That Depends. So Whatever the Input may be, I should transcodify it as USD. How is it possible?

Comment: @MindSwipe I am sorry for not being clear on the question. I am a newbie to programming. Will work on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking for is to deserialise some JSON into a dictionary, and then get the results for USD from said dictionary.

To deserialise your result into a dictionary you can use the static method `DeserializeObject<>` in `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

And to get the value "USD":

```
bool hasUSD = dictionary.TryGetValue("USD", out List<string> values);
```

And then use "values for your USD stuff if hasUSD is `true`.